# Why does the equality not hold for $(A \times B ) \cup ( C \times D ) \subset ( A \cup C ) \times ( B \cup D )$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have proved this expression but I want to prove that they both are not equal.
$$(A \times B ) \cup ( C \times D ) \subset ( A \cup C ) \times ( B \cup D )$$ 
May be I have to prove that $( A \cup C ) \times ( B \cup D )$  is not a subset of  $(A \times B ) \cup ( C \times D )$.

Answer (score 1):

If the four sets are disjoint, the set-theoretical equation becomes equivalent to the algebraic equation $ab+cd=(a+c)(b+d)$.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you only need to prove that there are sets $A,B,C,D$ such that an element of $(A\times B)\cup(C\times D)$ is not an element of $(A\cup C)\times(B\cup D)$.

You should be able to construct some simple sets and verify that this is true.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, and to prove that, you can try to construct a counter-example, i.e. try to define sets $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ such that one element of $( A \cup C ) \times ( B \cup D )$ is not in $(A \times B ) \cup ( C \times D )$. (Hint: use the empty set.)